# Graph SDK for .NET doesn't have Request method

Tags: azure, graph, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use the [Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) and NuGet 5.0.0-preview16 and forwarding the example it says to use `Request` method in example

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

but I have an error in the code:

> 'UsersRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request' and
> no accessible extension method 'Request' accepting a first argument of
> type 'UsersRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Fixed: I changed Microsoft.Graph on NuGet from 5.0.0-preview16 to 4.47.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C# SDK V5 `Request` method is removed and you can call directly `GetAsync` method.  But V5 is still in preview and it's better to use latest V4 version.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync();
```

Upgrade guide can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md).

Comment: Or PostAsync, e.g. the new way to create a folder is GetUserRequestBuilder().MailFolders.PostAsync(new MailFolder{DisplayName = "Error"})

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I changed Microsoft.Graph on NuGet from 5.0.0-preview16 to 4.47.0